# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following .... [PL/SQL]

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

function i created:

```
SQL> create or replace function sum(first number,second number) return number is result number:= 0; begin  result:=first+second; return result; end sum;
2 /

Function created.
```

and here is how i compile it:

```
set serveroutput on;
begin
dbms_output.put_line(sum(1,1));
end;
/
```

After compilation, appears the following error:

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 27:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:
) * & - + / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> ||
multiset
```

Comment: Considering `SUM` is a reserved word and a built-in aggregate function, it's a stupid choice for a custom function name. Try `ADD_NUMBERS` or something

Comment: @Bohemian thank you, i'm still learning and that was my first try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that this has to do with the fact that `SUM` is an existing function in PL/SQL. Try changing the name of your function to `MYSUM` or something and see if that fixes it.